# Create Array from Strings

Tags: javascript

I want to create an Array from strings

That is how the string is formatted

```
const someString = "a,b,c,d";
```

And I need an Array like this

```
const someArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split the string:

`const arr = "a,b,c,d".split(",")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.prototype.split()`

```
const someString = "a,b,c,d";
const someArray = someString.split(',');
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split